# 'object' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have this piece of code:

```
    sliderData () {
        let sliderData = this.product.slider; 

        sliderData.title = 'test';

        // {{ $t('related_product_slider_header', { category: 'hello', designer: 'hey' }) }}
        return sliderData;
    }
```

Then es-lint(prefer-const) warns me and tells me that:

```
'sliderData' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead.eslint(prefer-const)
```

But that's a lie, isn't it? I do reassign the object one line down.

I don't really get it.

Comment: You are not actually reassigning the object. The reference of sliderData is constant in this case, you are just changing a property value. If you switch to const your program will run ok

Answer (score 4):

You don't reassign `sliderData`. You change a property. As far as JS is concerned, "assigning" an object only ever refers to using it as the left hand term of the assignment operator as in:

`sliderData = someObject;`

So:

```
const sliderData = this.product.slider; 

sliderData.title = 'test'; //This is fine

sliderData = new Object(); //error
```

Note: This is because the value of "sliderData" is a *reference* containing the address of the object, not the object itself: this is also why equivalency fails between two objects unless one was assigned with the value of the other.

Answer (score 2):

You are not reassigning the address that `sliderData` is storing, you are simply mutating that object.

You can and should use `const` instead of `let`, because you are not reassigning the `sliderData` variable. If for exmaple you were to write `sliderData = 3`, this is reassigning, `sliderData.something = 3` is not reassigning.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not reassigning the `sliderData` its considered as an const. Though you declare an object as const you can add properties and edit values in it. Please see below:

```
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

// You can change a property:
car.color = "red";

// You can add a property:
car.owner = "Johnson";
```